# NameError: global name is not defined, why am I getting that error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, linked-list, nameerror

I am trying to implement some functions but I'm getting an error with len_link function:
**`NameError: global name 'len_link' is not defined`**
While the other function is working perfectly fine, any clue why this error is occurring in the first place?

```
class Solution:
        # @param A : head node of linked list
        # @param B : head node of linked list
        def len_link(A):
            temp=A.head
            count=0
            while(temp):
                count+=1
                temp=temp.next
            return count

        def longerlist(B,n):
            for i in range(n):
                B = B.next
            return B

        def getIntersectionNode(self, A, B):
            m = len_link(A)
            n = len_link(B)
            d = abs(m-n)
            if m>n :
                A = longerlist(A,n)
            elif m<n:
                B = longerlist(B,n)
            while A!= None and B!= None:
                if A.val == B.val:
                    return A
                A = A.next
                B = B.next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Solution.len_link` not just `len_link`.  Otherwise Python expects it to be a name at global scope.

Also, since `len_link` does not take a `self` parameter, it needs to be decorated with `@staticmethod`:

```
    @staticmethod
    def len_link(A):
```

Comment: Can you further explain why? as it's working without referring to the class name when it comes to other functions?
Adding to that, I tried your approach and now I'm getting this error:
TypeError: unbound method len_link() must be called with Solution instance as the first argument (got ListNode instance instead)

Comment: @RanX: Oh yes, you also need to add `@staticmethod`.  I updated my answer.  The reason why is that non-static methods are called like `self.foo()`, where `self` tells Python which class type to use.  A method with no `self` parameter cannot be looked up without an explicit class name before it.

Answer (score 1):

Or create a function outside of that class, by this you will able to call it globally or go with classname.functionname()